# Erro date_diff PHP

Tags: php, oracle, datetime

Estou fazendo um teste, com uma consulta em banco Oracle (gravando o sysdate, resultado: 13/09/2016 13:24:44) e me retornando no PHP. Preciso calcular a diferença, em horas e estava tentando a função abaixo:

```
$date_a = new DateTime($p_fim[$passo]);
$date_b = new DateTime($p_inicio[$passo]);

$interval = date_diff($date_a,$date_b);
echo $interval->format('%h:%i:%s');
```

Mas está retornando o erro abaixo:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (13/09/2016
>   13:24:44) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character'

Pesquisando no SO mesmo todos usam o formato 2016-09-13. É isso mesmo? Preciso converter antes de passar o valor?

Comment: Sim, o `date_diff` só aceita a string de data separadas com hífen. `-`, por exemplo; `13-09-16`, realize os teste e me avise se conseguir! depois coloco como resposta!

Comment: Tente isso: ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = '[date_format]'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esses são os tipos suportados, segundo a documentação:

```
const string ATOM = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP" ;
const string COOKIE = "l, d-M-Y H:i:s T" ;
const string ISO8601 = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sO" ;
const string RFC822 = "D, d M y H:i:s O" ;
const string RFC850 = "l, d-M-y H:i:s T" ;
const string RFC1036 = "D, d M y H:i:s O" ;
const string RFC1123 = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;
const string RFC2822 = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;
const string RFC3339 = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP" ;
const string RSS = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;
const string W3C = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP" ;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

O seu caso não possui um formato padronizado oficialmente, portanto, terá que fornecer um formato aceitável.

Veja um exemplo de como usar o método `DateTime::createFromFormat()`

```
$date_a = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '13/09/2016 13:24:44');
$date_b = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '13/09/2016 20:24:44');
$interval = date_diff($date_a,$date_b);
echo $interval->format('%H:%i:%s');
```

Sendo mais específico para o seu caso,

```
$date_a = new DateTime('d/m/Y H:i:s', $p_fim[$passo]);
```

Comment: Boa Daniel. Só fiz um ajuste aqui: echo $interval->format('%h:%m:%i'); Ai exibiu bem certo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Daniel, na virada de hora ocorre a situação abaixo, sabe como posso resolver?  D1 = 13/09/2016 14:46:12  d2 = 13/09/2016 15:00:41  DIFERENCA = 22:9:31

Comment: Desculpe, confundi as letras. Fiz a correção na resposta.  `H:i:s`. Estava errado como `H:m:i`